# Div overlay frame fitted

Tags: html, css

The goal I want to achieve:

- Have a picture "carousel"
- frame rests in place while images inside appear and disappear but gets resized according the images' size. The frame is a png with just the outer part colored.

Would I need a outer div that changes its size according to its inner img-tag with another div that will always stay on top (serving another image as png-frame) of the image no matter how the size of the img-tag changes?

Any structure of tags and styles is welcome, perhaps inner divs or spans or whatever. JavaScript is an option but I would very well be interested in a pure CSS approach.

```html
<div id="outer">
    <img id="frameOnTop" src="...">
    <img id="image" src="...">
</div>
```

***EDITED***

WORKING EXAMPLE:

https://codepen.io/xdx950/pen/eYYXjBa

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? Can you add a list of ressources you searched and tried? Also post a picture or what you want to achieve.

Comment: check this link: https://codepen.io/xdx950/pen/YzzgvVK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I found a way to do this without needing javascript:

```js
const innerBottom =  document.getElementById("inner-bottom");
const resizeButton = document.getElementById("resize-button");

function resize() {
 const newSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
  console.log(`Setting new size to ${newSize}`);
  innerBottom.style.height = newSize + "px";
  innerBottom.style.width = newSize + "px";
};

resizeButton.addEventListener("click", resize);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s
}

#outer {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

#inner-bottom, #inner-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#inner-bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#inner-top {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  z-index: 2;
  border: red 2px dotted;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <img id="inner-bottom" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/09/19/02/dog-bitch-3665315_960_720.jpg" />
  <img id="inner-top" />
</div>

<button id="resize-button">
resize!
</button>
```

Comment: this indeed works, the image size should not be changed and preserved as the intrinsic size and as of the js part, it all seems to work but is there no CSS approach to this? It seems to be a no-brainer but i can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: It all uses javascript to read the current size value of the `inner-bottom` size and use these values to set the `outer` size. I did use CSS to automatically change the size of the `inner-top` automatically to the size of the `outer` element.

Comment: It is indeed a very useful appraoch but the interval inside the js is a bit clumsy, which event-trigger would you use to register a change of the image inside the #outer element?

Comment: If you could explain why there is no pure CSS approach and put that statement inside your answer I will surely mark it as answered!

Comment: @diesdasananas I have updated my answer to reflect a method without using javascript.